# Dynamically generated tabItems

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Right now I'm using `uiOutput` with `renderUI` to show my content. But I wanna use Google Analytics, so I must work with `tabItems` for tracking pages of my app. But it doesn't work for me.

Simple example of my code:

```r
UI <- dashboardPagePlus(
  header = dashboardHeaderPlus(...),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    ...,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItemOutput(
        outputId = 'EventsMenu'
      ),
      ...
    ),
  body = dashboardBody(
    ...,
    uiOutput(
      outputID = 'EventsBody'
    ),
    ...
  )
)

Server <- function(
  input,
  output
) {
  output$EventsMenu <- renderMenu(
    {
      lapply(
        X = 1:10,
        FUN = function(
          ID
        ) {
          menuItem(
            text = 'Event',
            tabName = paste0(
              'Event',
              ID
            )
          )
        }
      )
    }
  )
  ...
  output$EventsBody <- renderUI(
    {
      if(
        stri_detect(
          str = 'Event'
        )
      ) {
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            ...
          )
        )
      }
    }
  )
  ...
}

shinyApp(
 ui = UI,
 server = Server
)
```

How could I change my code for using `tabItems`?

Comment: tried your code - there are so many errors, it's hard to find the one you meant..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deal it with `shiny.router`
So my menu item looks like:

```r
menuItem(
    text = "Homepage",
    href = route_link(
        path = "Home"
    ),
    newtab = FALSE
)
```